# Embedding a Spring Integration app into Apache Karaf

Tags: spring, spring-integration, apache-karaf

I am in the process of developing a Spring app. As it stands the app is currently run as follows by a main class:

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Bootstrap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-integration-demo.xml");
    }

}
```

I would like to **integrate my app into [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/)** (or integrate Apache Karaf into my app?).

I am not sure where and how to start. Can someone please provide basic advice and/or pointer to relevant documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my app has to be an OSGI bundle. Furthermore all its jars/dependencies also have to be bundles.

A good way to deploy the bundles is to drop them into the /deploy directory of Karaf.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know what a bundle is, or what is OSGi, but more important **why** there was the need of osgi, then I will strongly suggest to first read OSGi in Action, then try a few samples, only after that think about coding bundles - there is a very good maven plugin for that.

Yu need to understand that OSGi solves (but also creates - like, problems with JNDI and Classloaders in an OSGi container, it almost does not care about private,public or protected - or to be more confusing here - it adds something like, bundle specific visibility, which you need to understand) a lot of your problems, BUT if you do not understand which are these or how it exactly solves them, then coding into OSGi is just, well, useless.

From what I remember Spring offers almost all their jars as bundles already - you have to look into the repository.

btw, Apache Karaf is just an OSGi container - but a very good one. You should read it's documentation also.